# How to align figures when a long subcaption causes misalignment

Tags: tables, minipage

I'm using `tabular` and `minipage` environment to align 4 figures in 2 x 2 layout. Although the four figures have the same sizes, the lengths of the subcaptions are different and that causes misalignment in the figures. Is there any way to correct this?

[image]

Below is the code I'm using:

```latex
\documentclass[compress]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[hang,footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\title[]{Beamer title}
\author[]{Author name}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            % Figure 1
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\hsize}
                \centering 
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, scale=0.3]{sample.jpg}
                \subcaption{Subcaption}
            \end{minipage}
            % Figure 2
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
                \centering 
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, scale=0.3]{sample.jpg}
                \subcaption{Longer longer longer longer longer longer longer subcaption}
            \end{minipage}
            \\
            % Figure 3
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\hsize}
                \centering 
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, scale=0.3]{sample.jpg}
                \subcaption{Longer longer longer longer longer longer longer subcaption}
            \end{minipage}
            % Figure 4
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\hsize}
                \centering 
                \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, scale=0.3]{sample.jpg}
                \subcaption{Subcaption}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[t]` so they top-align (`keepaspectratio` is doing nothing here)

Comment: Thank you, @DavidCarlisle! It worked perfectly!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, You are right. Disabling `keepaspectratio` did not change anything. Is the image aspect preserved by default in `minipage`?

Comment: minipage is unrelated, scale applies equally  to x and y, keept aspectratio  is just needed if you specify both width and height, so only one is used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\begin{minipage}[t]` so they top-align (or simpler remove the `minipage` and use `p{.45\textwidth}` columns instead of `c`

Answer (score 5):

Use `\subcaptionbox` (section 2 of the manual of `subcaption`).

> The `\subcaptionbox` command typesets given content and caption. It automatically aligns the sub-figures resp. sub-tables by their very first caption line.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[hang,footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\title[]{Beamer title}
\author[]{Author name}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
  % Figure 1
  \subcaptionbox{Subcaption}[0.45\textwidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image}%
  } &
  % Figure 2
  \subcaptionbox{%
    Longer longer longer longer longer longer longer subcaption%
  }[0.45\textwidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image}%
  } \\
  % Figure 3
  \subcaptionbox{%
    Longer longer longer longer longer longer longer subcaption%
  }[0.45\textwidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image}%
  } &
  % Figure 4
  \subcaptionbox{Subcaption}[0.45\textwidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image}%
  }
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]